# Open a html file in chrome using a relative path

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I am trying to open a HTML file with a relative path using PowerShell, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
Start-Process "chrome" -Argument ".\_reports\html-results.html"
```

I need a relative path because this script can run in any folder and has to open this HTML file in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to determine the script path using the `$MyInvocation` variable. Then you should combine the path using the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Start-Process "chrome" -Argument (Join-Path $scriptPath ".\_reports\html-results.html")
```